# Django request/response multithreading

Tags: python, django, multithreading, request, response

The workflow of my app is -

```
User submits a file
On receiving -> process_file()
return response
```

This could result in timeouts if the `process_file()` takes much time, so how could I send back the `response` before and then process the file and send the desired output to user later.
I have checked out django-celery but I think it's quite heavy for a small app which I am trying to build.

**Update:** I searched a bit around on the internet, and if anyone would like to use celery, here is a nice blog post, that could help you solve this situation - [[Link]](https://realpython.com/blog/python/asynchronous-tasks-with-django-and-celery/)

Comment: You need an async queue : https://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/workers-queues-tasks/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/) for that matter:

> Celery is an asynchronous task queue/job queue based on distributed message passing. It is focused on real-time operation, but supports scheduling as well.
>
> The execution units, called tasks, are executed concurrently on a single or more worker servers using multiprocessing, Eventlet,   or gevent. Tasks can execute asynchronously (in the background) or synchronously (wait until ready).

Comment: Thanks, It seems like I should better stick to celery, rather than other stuff.

Comment: Welcome, that's where I ended up anyway too.